# Python: check if one set can be created from another sets

Tags: python, set

I have list of sets:

```
graphs = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}]
```

I have to check if `input` set can be created as sum of sets inside `graphs`.
For example:

```
input1 = {1, 2, 3, 6} # answer - True
input2 = {1, 2, 3, 4} # answer - False, because "4" is only a part of another set, only combinations of full sets are required
```

In other words, there are all combinations of sets inside `graphs`:

```
{1, 2, 3}
{4, 5}
{6}
{1, 2, 3, 6}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
{4, 5, 6}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

I need to know, if one of these combinations is equal to `input`.

How should I correctly iterate through `graphs` elements to get answer? If `graphs` is bigger, there would be some problems with finding all the combinations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking at this the wrong way.  I think it is better to remove any set that contains an element you cannot use (i.e. remove set `{4,5}` when you are looking for `{1,2,3,4}`.  Then create `union` of all other sets and see if this is equal to your input set.

This way you will not need to find all combinations, just a (at most) O(n*len(sets)) elimination step at first.

```
graphs = [i for i in graphs if i.issubset(input1)  ]
```

check for answer:

```
result = set().union(*graphs) == input1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find all combinations with `itertools.combinations`, then simply compare the sets:

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

def check(graphs, inp):
    for i in range(1, len(graphs)+1):
        for p in combinations(graphs, i):
            if set(chain(*p)) == inp:
                return True
    return False

graphs = [{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}]
input1 = {1, 2, 3, 6}
input2 = {1, 2, 3, 4}

print(check(graphs, input1))
print(check(graphs, input2))
```

Prints:

```
True
False
```